# AutoSuggest Append In textBox From Gridview Data?

Tags: c#, linq

i have a datagrid in which their is a field named StudentName ......And I have a text box from which i have to find students by thier name i make function for this but i want textbox auto suggest and append students name by data present in grid not from database What i do ........

i take all the student name in a ilist below is my code .........

```
 try
                    {
                        IList<string> ObjAutoCompleteStringCollection = new List<string>();                  
                        for(int i=0;i<dgvStudentDetail.RowCount;i++)
                        {
                             ObjAutoCompleteStringCollection.Add(dgvStudentDetail.Rows[i].Cells["StudentName"].Value.ToString());
                        }
                       txtStudentName.AutoCompleteCustomSource=
                       txtStudentName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                       txtStudentName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                   }
```

Comment: nice question..i too had this problem

Comment: If my code didn't work for you, **your problem is in fact very strange and it should be somewhere else in your project**. The code I posted should work. You can try creating new blank project and test it.

Comment: If you want decent answers, please apply decent formatting.

Comment: @Co.Aden I even don't understand what's the actual problem of the OP, **it's simply an autocomplete problem which is simple**, we have all the built-in properties to play with. **I doubt that You and Sandeep Singh Hada are the same person** and you have even 3 accounts in SO, right? `Co. Aden, Sandeep Singh Hada` and the third is still a secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an `AutoCompleteStringCollection` as `Custom Source` for your auto complete source:

```
try
{
   txtStudentName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();                  
   for(int i=0;i<dgvStudentDetail.RowCount;i++){
    txtStudentName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(dgvStudentDetail.Rows[i].Cells["StudentName"].Value.ToString());
   }
   txtStudentName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
   txtStudentName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

**NOTE**: your `txtStudentName` should have `Multiline = false` (which is by default), otherwise the `AutoCompleting` won't work.

Comment: i did the same as above mentioned but textbox does'nt suggest and append any thing What i do???

Comment: @SandeepSinghHada your original code **can't work** because you use an `IList` as custom source but the custom should **can only be an AutoCompleteStringCollection**. You should check if your `dgvStudentDetail` has some `visible data`. When testing, please type in the appropriate string, such as if the custom source has `abcde`, you should type in `a` to see it in action. BTW, you should copy exactly my code.

Comment: I talk about the above answer of my question i did the same but it dose'nt suggest append me ..............

Comment: @SandeepSinghHada looks like you don't understand my comment well? I doubt that **you don't understand how suggesting and appending work**. As I said, if your custom source contained only `1234`, `234`, `345` and you typed in `456`,`45`... you might think that **it doesn't work** but that's how it works. You have to type in `1`,`2` or `3` to see it work.

Comment: i did same bro i understand what u said for eg i have name Amit,avinash ,abhinav and so on i want that if i write a in textbox it suggest me all three names

Comment: Could down-voters leave some comment explaining why?

Comment: @SandeepSinghHada you should post more code, the code I posted is **very simple and how to set up a simple custom auto complete source for a textbox**

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either. @SandeepSinghHada If an answer "is not working" for you, try do give a descriptive comment, not a comment that triggers downvotes. Certainly don't downvote yourself immediately (sorry if you didn't). People tend to pile on downvotes. BTW there's not even a decent problem description in your question.